# Chain Observable RxJs in Angular

Tags: angular, rxjs, rxjs-observables

I use RxJs 6.6.0 and Angular 9.

I have two functions which returns Observable<'Class1'> and Observable<'number'>.

so I use to:

```
funcA().subscribe(x=>{ // do something...});

funcB().subscribe(x=>{// do somethings..});
```

But I need to call funcB only when funcA() is finish. I see than concat may be helpful but I can't get the two answers like that

```
concat(funcA,funcB).subscribe( (x,y)=>{// do with x
//do with y});
```

I would like to do this because parameters of funcB depend of the return of funcA.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use `switchMap` from rxjs/operators to achieve it.

```
this.sub = funcA()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(valueFromA => {
      // use valueFromA in here.
      return funcB()
    })
  )
  .subscribe();
```

Comment: Why use `switchMap`?

Comment: Because: On each emission the previous inner observable (the result of the function you supplied) is cancelled and the new observable is subscribed.

Comment: In case `mergeMap`, the inner subscription you have to manually control. By using `switchMap` it cancel automatically. That helps to avoid the memory leaks issue in case you forget to unsubscribe manually. [MergeMap Docs](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap)

Comment: @VaritJPatel valuefromA need to be assign to a filed of an object I give to funcB and not give directly the value. Remeber than FuncB return an observable

Comment: @RafiHenig I use the observer to get just one value from an api rest I develop

Comment: @Arno I showed you how you can use the value valuefromA to call  funcB().

Comment: @rafihenig - what do you mean with obsA will never emit again when you use switchMap..? I really don’t understand that statement..

Comment: although in this case the `funcA` only emits once (http request) so there's no need for  `switchMap`

Answer (score 2):

Try implementing it in the following way:

```js
import {  mergeMap } from 'rxjs/operators';

funcA()
  .pipe(
     mergeMap(valueFromA => {
         funcB({value: valueFromA }))
     }
   )
  .subscribe(console.log);
```

Comment: I can't use the return of funcA and I need to asign this value to an object I give to funcB